# How to get URL of a popup login window?

Tags: testing, web, locust

I want to write a locustfile for load testing. There is a local host on my system which I want to test (A social network called Oxwall). I need the user to login to Oxwall and then do some tasks, but my problem is how can I send user data for login? The login window is a popup which doesn't have any urls, so I can't use POST method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not only this. I want to write a scenario which user uploads a photo and again the upload process is popup (not in a separate page with its own url). Also you can see what I mean at https://demo.oxwall.com/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the login process it's on a popup or at an specific url. It will end up using an authentication mechanism where you submit some login credentials mostly to an URL endpoint, API or service. That's what you need to replicate in your locust file